# How to get lilypond to generate glissando in midi output

Tags: midi, lilypond

My lilypond snippet generates a score, containing a glissando (slide from one pitch to another) correctly. It generates a midi file, but it doesn't sound like a slide from one pitch to another. It sounds like 2 distinct pitches. My instrument is set to violin.

What is the correct way to generate glissando in midi file?

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "articulate.ly"


\score {
  \articulate
  <<
  \new Staff {
    \set Staff.midiInstrument = #"violin"

    \relative a' {
      a4 \glissando d
    }
  }
  >>  
  \layout { }
  \midi { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

LilyPond unfortunately does not support glissandi in its MIDI output.

Answer (score 1):

LilyPond can't produce a midi glissando automatically, (even in the latest version 2.23), but you can make one manually:

The trick is to use seperate score blocks for the pdf and midi, and to use [tags](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/different-editions-from-one-source#using-tags) that are filtered out of these blocks (with `\removeWithTag`).

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "articulate.ly"

contents = {
    <<
        \new Staff {
            \set Staff.midiInstrument = #"violin"
            \relative a' {
                \tag #'pdfonly {
                    a4 \glissando^\markup{\italic"gliss."} d r2 |
                }
                \tag #'midionly {
                    \tuplet 5/4 {a16 ais b c cis} d4 r2 |
                }
            }
        }
    >>  
}

% PDF
\score {
    \removeWithTag #'midionly
    \contents
    \layout { }
}

% MIDI
\score {
    \removeWithTag #'pdfonly
    \articulate
    \contents
    \midi { }
}
```

- I've used a `\tuplet` to fit in all of the discrete pitches between the notes.  A really glissando will not be discrete but this is as good as you can get with a midi.
- I've also moved the `\articulate.ly` script into the midi block.  It makes sense to apply this script the midi, but it messes up the pdf.